# mono command line unit testing

Tags: testing, mono, nunit, monodevelop

I wrote a few nunit tests that I've run successfully in nunit on win7, and via MonoDevelop on my mac.

What I'd like to do now is run these tests non-stop (or until I kill it). I can't see any way to tell MonoDevelop to keep running over and over, so I'm trying to do this via the commandline.

Is there a way to run the MonoDevelop testing tool from the command line? I don't need reporting (my tests already report internally), just re-triggering every few minutes.

If there was a commandline tool, I could just wrap it in fabric or a shell script and just run it over and over...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you  just use the normal nunit command line? It is contained with the standard Mono installation, available as `nunit-console` command.

Comment: can I do that on os x? I didn't think nunit ran as-is off windows.